# How to reset variables at midnight? - React Native mobile application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I'm creating a mobile application using React Native where the user can create a task and dedicate a certain amount of time for that task daily. I'm using React Hooks and AsyncStorage to change and store my data.

The main screen is supposed to display a list of the user's tasks as well as how long he needs to work on that task. The screen should show how long the user has to work on the task daily (in blue text) and how much time is left for the task to be completed (in red text).

The problem is that I want the values in the red font to reset to the same values at the blue text when a new day begins (aka midnight). So far I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
        let newList = allRoutines;

        newList.forEach((item) => {
            item.timeLeft = item.time;
        });

        writeItemToStorage(newList);
    }, moment("24:00:00", "hh:mm:ss").diff(moment()) );
```

What is the best way to do what I need the app to do.

Please Help!!
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to solve this:

1. There are some [possible issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981#issuecomment-652745831) with `setTimeout` but you can use a `setInterval` that runs every minute and checks if the date has changed. This could be ok, but you have to be careful with this approach. It's easy to introduce performance issues here.
2. Bridge into native code. There are native APIs you can take advantage of that will alert you when the day has changed. You can tie into iOS's system notification or Android's broadcast receiver which also lets you account for scenarios where the date changes as a result of a timezone change depending on which notifications you want to subscribe to.

If you like the sound of option #2, we created [`react-native-midnight`](https://github.com/ravnhq/react-native-midnight) which does all the native work for you and is pretty easy to hook up.